# why is rabbit mq version 3.6.14 not in maven repo and why on rabbitmq site it shows 3.6.7

Tags: java, maven, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, spring-rabbit

The rabbit mq site has the client version as 3.6.14 as the max version
https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.6.14/

Why is this not on on maven repository, am i looking at the wrong place ?

Maven site which has only 3.6.6 as the max 3.6.x version, please see
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client

Also on the page https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.6.14/

The version is 3.6.7 why would that be ? on a page which says 3.6.14 the version is 3.6.7.

```
[   ]   amqp-client-3.6.7-SNAPSHOT.jar  07-Nov-2017 10:13   432K
[TXT]   amqp-client-3.6.7-SNAPSHOT.jar.asc  07-Nov-2017 10:13   801
[   ]   rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.6.14.zip 07-Nov-2017 10:13   105K
[TXT]   rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.6.14.zip.asc 07-Nov-2017 10:13   801
[DIR]   rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.6.14/    07-Nov-2017 10:13   -
```

Do I need a pivotal ticket ? Or is there someone from pivotal who can answer this ?

We are interested in this fix for our live environments and not able to move to version 5 as of now. This fix is in version 3.6.10 .

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/rabbitmq_v3_6_10/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/WorkPool.java

This is the original issue in stackoverflow

[Maximum permit count exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588620/maximum-permit-count-exceeded)

Comment: You should ask questions about rabbitmq on the `rabbitmq-users` Google group - that's where the RabbitMQ engineers hang out.

Comment: cool thanks will search and do that

Comment: Thanks much Gary found the answer i needed at the rabbitmq-users forum, here is a link  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/Ro-Z3S9GZww